# Count column occurrences in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say i have a table column with these values: 
1, 
1, 
1, 
5, 
3, 
3, 
1. 
Using SQL I want to count occurrences of each value and then display the most frequent one, e.g the result should be 4 because we have four values of one's?

Answer (score 0):

You can just do a `GROUP BY` of that column, order them by counts in descending order and limit the output by 1 because you want the highest count value.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, COUNT(*) AS COL_FREQUENCY
FROM YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY COLUMN_NAME
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```